# Disable the inline editing to force users to click on "Edit all" to make changes on sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I am curious to if this setting exists.

For my usecase, I have a power Automate trigger on save and checks if a status is changed. It then sends out an email with the value from the next column (user assigned). The problem is that it is triggering multiple times due to the page being modified. I would prefer if I can disable this page from having inline editing and force them to click on the Edit all. Is there is a way to do that change?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force users to click Edit All to make changes on Sharepoint, follow the below steps:

1. Go to the list settings >> Click on the “Advanced settings” link.
2. In the Advanced Settings link, scroll down, and Under the “Quick property editing” option, choose “No” for “Allow items in this list to be edited using Quick Edit?” and then click OK.

[image]

Comment: Did my response answer your question? If I misunderstand something, please let me know! If there is any other assistance i can provide, please feel free to let me know, i will do our best to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, currently there is no SharePoint out of the box way available to prevent users from editing the individual column values from "display/view" form of list item and force them to click "Edit all" button at the top of the list form.

However, if you can inform users to use this option, flow will run only once when they save the list form after making the changes:

[image]

Comment: Yeah that is actually the workaround I have with a big "USE EDIT ALL" in red.

Comment: Another option would be to customize the list form using Power Apps and always open it in "Edit" mode instead of "view" mode. Check: [Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224).